# Сборка операционной системы Линукс

Tags: сборка, обновления, linux

Уважаемые, подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку, где можно прочесть подробную технологию сборки Линукса любой модификации.

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Интересно, что имеется ввиду from scratch, gentoo, slackware или что-то ещё?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще у каждого дистрибутива свой подход

Я вот по ubuntu live-dvd писал в прошлом году: [Пересборка дистрибутивов на базе Ubuntu](http://samlug.ru/book/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE-/-faq/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Про сборку всей системы из исходников: [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable/LFS-BOOK-7.1-NOCHUNKS.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Часть I. Дистрибутивы ALT Linux](http://docs.altlinux.org/archive/2.4/master/alt-docs-faq/pt01.html).

> Frequently Asked Questions About ALT Linux products

Answer (score 1):

[Gentoo Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/) для коллекции :)